# SPEL expressions not evaluated dynamically

Tags: spring-security, spring-el

I am trying to filter URLs using spring security. Following is a definition for filtering:

> <intercept-url pattern="/page" access="#{new java.io.File('file_path').exists()}"/>

The URL is restricted based on existence of a file called file_path.

If the file_path exists at the time the spring configuration file is loaded, the access is provided. If the file_path is created after load, access is not provided. I would like the expression to be evaluated every time the request to /page is made & not just during compilation of the expression.

Tried to set the system property -Dspring.expression.compiler.mode=MIXED but there is no effect.

Can anybody please help me in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct because you use the `configuration time` expression (`#{...}`). To achieve the requirements you should use something like this:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*"
           access="hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')"/>
</http>
```

See [Expression-Based Access Control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access). So, in your case it can be like this:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/page" access="new java.io.File('file_path').exists()"/>
</http>
```